# MySQL auto_increment de 2 em 2 (2, 4, 6...)

Tags: mysql, sql

Como faço SQL auto_increment para fazer o incremento do numero de 2 em 2 (2, 4, 6...) em um campo identificador?

```sql
create table cliente (
    idcliente int not null auto_increment,
    nome varchar(40) not null,
    cpf char(11) unique not null,
    nascimento date not null,
    sexo enum('F','M') not null,
    email varchar(40) unique not null,
    nacionalidade varchar(10) default 'Brasil',
    primary key (idcliente)
) default charset = utf8;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686327/change-the-step-auto-increment-fields-increment-by

Comment: Tem que editar o seu my.cnf e configurar auto_increment_increment = 2  ou sobre linha de comando configurar a variavél usando set dessa forma: SET @@auto_increment_increment=2;
Resposta dada em comentário porque o @Motta já tinha apontado um post que explica a funcionalidade.

Comment: @Motts, Rafael Salomão. Seria bom se um de vocês dois (ou ambos) postassem uma resposta para que eu possa votar positivamente :).